# Projection of vector x in subspace L

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

> Given vector $x$ in Euclidean space and $L$ is a subspace of the Euclidean space and the basis $a$ = {$a_{1}$,$a_{2}$} in $L$ where $x$, $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ are the following:

$x=\begin{pmatrix}
3\\ 
4
\end{pmatrix}$

$a_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix}$

$a_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$

The approach followed for the above formulation was by making a basis matrix i.e. $A$ as:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2\\ 
-1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

The projection matrix was found by the following formula:

$P=A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}$

Plugging in the values, $P$ came out to be:

$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Thus for getting the projection of $x$ in subspace $L$, multiply the projection matrix i.e. $P$ with $x$.
But the answer coming is not correct. Can you please let me know where it is going wrong in the above approach?

Comment: What is the subspace $L$? $a_1,a_2$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ so projecting onto the space of $a_1,a_2$ will just give $x$. You should have got $P=I$.

Comment: $L$ is subspace of the euclidean space.sorry my bad i will update it. Yes i am getting $P=I$. The basis is in subspace L.

Comment: The answer is correct in the sense that $\{a_1, a_2\}$ span $\mathbb{R}^2$ and thus projection of $x$ will be $x$ itself. However, if you also wish to express $x$ in the basis $a = \{a_1, a_2\}$, then it will be different from $x$ and will be given by $y = (-5/2, 3/2)^T$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 thanks i tried but not getting the correct answer.

Comment: What is the subspace $L$?

Comment: subspace L has basis a and is a subspace of euclidean space.

Comment: Well, the space is two dimensional and hence $L$ is the entire space. Hence projecting $x$ onto $L$ will just give $x$, which is what you have.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks